# iOS 7 Views not resizing or hiding

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I've got a problem that I've been banging on for weeks. Please help. I have an iOS 7 app that has  view with the nav bar, a view with an embedded text field (addressBarView) and a web view. I'm implementing the WebScriptObject (I'm not concerned about iTunes store passability) so that the web page JavaScript can fire Objective C methods. That works great until I fire a methods that are supposed to hide the nav bar and address bar.

Here's the view...

[image: The View]

...and here's the subview's structs and springs...

[image: addressBarView]

[image: urlTextField]

[image: webView]

When a web page is loaded the `META` tags are inspected. If they say `<meta http-equiv="hidenavbar" content="true">` or `<meta http-equiv="hideaddressbar" content="true">` then the `showHideNavBar` or `showHideNavBar` methods below are fired. These work great.

Now here's what doesn't

I won't bore you with the specifics on the WebScriptObject, but here's the relative code segment.

```
#pragma mark - webScript Bridge

+ (NSString *)webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)sel {
    // Naming rules can be found at:http://goo.gl/GAkziE
    if (sel == @selector(showHideAddressBar::)) {return @"showHideAddressBar";} else
    if (sel == @selector(showHideNavBar::)) {return @"showHideNavBar";}
}
```

Because all UI changes have to be done on the main thread I do this...

```
- (void)showHideNavBar:(BOOL)hide :(BOOL)animate {
    NSDictionary *navBarOptions = @{@"hide": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhd", hide],
                                    @"animate": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhd", animate]};
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(navBarState:) withObject:navBarOptions waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

.

```
- (void)showHideAddressBar:(BOOL)hide :(BOOL)animate {
    NSDictionary *adrBarOptions = @{@"hide": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhd", hide],
                                   @"animate": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhd", animate]};
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addressBarState:) withObject:adrBarOptions waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Then comes the really funky stuff.

```
- (void)navBarState:(NSDictionary *)navBarOptions {
    float addressBarY = navBarHidden ? 20.0f : 0.0f;
    BOOL animate = [navBarOptions[@"animate"] boolValue];
    BOOL hide = [navBarOptions[@"hide"] boolValue];
    float webViewY = addressBarY + (addressBarHidden ? 0.0f : 40.0f);
    float webViewHeight = [self view].frame.size.height - webViewY;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    if (hide && !navBarHidden) {
        navBarHidden = YES;
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animate];
    }
    else if (!hide && navBarHidden) {
        navBarHidden = NO;
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animate];
    }

    CGRect rectAddrBar = self.addressBarView.frame;
    rectAddrBar.origin.y = addressBarY;
    self.addressBarView.frame = rectAddrBar;

    CGRect rectWebView = self.webView.frame;
    rectWebView.origin.y = webViewY;
    rectWebView.size.height = webViewHeight;
    self.webView.frame = rectWebView;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.view layoutSubviews];
    });
}
```

.

```
- (void)addressBarState:(NSDictionary *)adrBarOptions {
    float addressBarY = navBarHidden ? 20.0f : 0.0f;
//    BOOL animate = [adrBarOptions[@"animate"] boolValue];
    BOOL hide = [adrBarOptions[@"hide"] boolValue];
    float webViewY = addressBarY + (addressBarHidden ? 0.0f : 40.0f);
    float webViewHeight = [self view].frame.size.height - webViewY;

    if (hide && addressBarHidden == NO) {
        addressBarHidden = YES;
        self.addressBarView.hidden = YES;
        self.urlTextField.hidden = YES;
        webViewY = addressBarY;
        webViewHeight = [self view].frame.size.height - webViewY;
    } else if (!hide && addressBarHidden == YES) {
        addressBarHidden = NO;
        self.addressBarView.hidden = NO;
        self.urlTextField.hidden = NO;
        webViewY = self.addressBarView.frame.size.height;
        webViewHeight = [self view].frame.size.height - webViewY;
    }
    CGRect rectAddrBar = self.addressBarView.frame;
    rectAddrBar.origin.y = addressBarY;
    self.addressBarView.frame = rectAddrBar;

    CGRect rectWebView = self.webView.frame;
    rectWebView.origin.y = webViewY;
    rectWebView.size.height = webViewHeight;
    self.webView.frame = rectWebView;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.view layoutSubviews];
    });
}
```

Here's the normal state.

[image: Normal State]

Here's when the nav and address bars are hidden on web page load with the META tag directive to hide the bars.

[image: Web Page Load]

Now, when the bars are hidden and I navigate off the page and return I get this.

[image: bad!]

I this screen shot I pulled down the web page so you can see that the address bar is hiding behind the nav bar

When I set a break point at the view update point I see that the main thread is being used.

[image: threads]

I've tried many patterns to get this to work. I've tried not using the dispatch_async (crashes app), using layoutIfNeeded, layoutSubviews, etc. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya know, one character can make or break your sanity. The method that starts the show/hide action, `webScriptNameForSelector`, is a class method. I had to make instance variables for the UI elements I needed to manipulate.